# Debian testing 'bullseye' logs out user while in sleepmode

Tags: debian, gnome3, bugs

since some resent upgrades of my Debian testing/bullseye distribution, my user gets logged out while in sleep-mode (lid closed).

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-5-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

I'm using Gnome 3 desktop:

```
GNOME Shell 3.30.2
```

does anyone know how to fix this or which package is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Just logged out or does the machine maybe shutdown instead of suspending? I've had a similar issue on my Arch for a few months now.

Comment: @terdon no it is not shutdown, it takes a view seconds and I get back to the login window. The machine does not go through the whole boot process again.

Comment: when this happened to me on some older software, it meant XWayland crashed (which gnome-shell treats as fatal). in my case it was SIGBUS *which is not logged by the kernel, unlike SIGSEGV*. So, you can look in your kernel logs (`journalctl _TRANSPORT=kernel`), but if that is not helpful I would recommend installing the `systemd-coredump` package and trying again.

Comment: @sourcejedi do I need the `logout` happen before doing the coredump?

Comment: Yes. 1) install `systemd-coredump` 2) put your computer to sleep and see that the unwanted "logout" bug happens 3) to start with, look in the overall system log e.g. `journalctl --since=-15minutes`, or `journalctl -b` (all logs from current boot).  A coredump should not be too hard to find in the log, because `journalctl` highlights errors in red, also coredumpd tries to log a backtrace which will be several lines long. And to just list coredumps, use `coredumpctl`.